# Haskell - Writing foldr recursively

Tags: haskell, recursion

I am trying to write the library function foldr using recursion. However, I am getting syntax errors and not sure about the functional correctness. This is my code:

```
foldr :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
foldr f [] = []
foldr f xs = foldr f (init xs) : f (last xs)
```

I would appreciate it if I can get some help on this

Comment: What are the type level errors? You should include them in your post!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not the type of the `foldr` function.  That is the type of the `map` function.

But that said, `:` concatenates *one* element to the *front* of a list.  The way you are using it attempts to concatenate one element to the *end* of a list, which does not work.

The closest thing to what you mean -- which is still O(n^2) and deeply inefficient -- is to replace the last line with

```
foldr f xs = foldr f (init xs) ++ [f (last xs)]
```